# Saying that a set is a subset of random elements from another set?

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory

For context, I'm looking to prove one of DeMorgan's Laws (I just started reading [AFCLA](http://linear.ups.edu/); I'm on the section where set notation is being introduced). The one I'm trying to prove, in particular, is

$$ \overline{(S \cup T)} = \overline{S} \cap \overline{T}  $$

To start with, I'm stating the following:

$$ S \subset U $$ and $$ T \subset V $$

However, I want to specify some constraints on $U$ and $V$.

How can I say something like $U \in \{\mathbb{R}|$ elements of $U$ are completely random and not necessarily restricted within some range or ordered sequence, with the assertion that $U \subset \mathbb{R}$ $\}$?

While I do want to really get this whole set notation thing down, I don't want to over-think this, so please let me know if this is just too much and effectively would require another proof on its own.

I appreciate the help.

**Edit**

Rewrote the question for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually for the complement (You denote it as $\overline S$) to make sense, both $S$ and $T$ must be subsets of the same universe $U$. There is no need to further specify $U$ other than

- $U$ is a set
- $S\subset U$ and $T\subset U$
- The complement is built in $U$, i.e. $\overline S = \{x\in U \mid x\notin S\}$.